# maximum call stack size exceeded on converting file

Tags: javascript, arraybuffer

I am converting a large byte array into a string using

```js
 var arrayBuffer = e.target.result,
          array = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);
 binaryString = String.fromCharCode.apply(null, array);
```

Here `e.target.result` is a image. It is working properly but if image size is bigger i'll get error `maximum call stack size exceeded`.
How can i resolved this ??

Thanks in advance........

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var base64 = btoa(new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer).reduce(
    function (data, byte) {
        return data + String.fromCharCode(byte);
    },
    ''
));
```